# determine outcome based on previous values in a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with the following format:

```
pair group group_rank win_prob
<int> <int>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1     1      first     0.6
 1     2      second    0.4
 2     3      first     0.5
 2     4      second    0.5
```

It has been produced with the following code snippet:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(pair = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2),
            group = seq(1:4),
            group_rank = c("first", "second", "first", "second"),
            win_prob = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5))
```

My goal is to assign "win" to one group in each pair and "loss" to
the other group. In other words, I want to produce the following
dataframe with a new column outcome:

```
pair group group_rank win_prob outcome
<int> <int>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>  
  1     1     first       0.6   win    
  1     2     second      0.4   loss   
  2     3     first       0.5   loss   
  2     4     second      0.5   win
```

The assignment of "win" or "loss" to the outcome variable should
be based on the group_rank and the corresponding value in the win_prob
variable. More specifically, each time I want first to check whether
the group with group_rank == "first" has won, by checking whether
its win_prob >= runif(1) (a Bernoulli trail).

If the condition is satisfied, I want to assign "win" to this
group. If the condition is not satisfied, I want to assign "loss".

After I have determined whether the group with group_rank == "first" has
won or not, I want to assign the opposite outcome to the group with
group_rank == "second". Therefore, if the "first" group has been
assigned "win", the second group should be assigned "loss" and
vice versa.

In pseudo-code, it should be something like this, but the trick is how to look within a grouped dataframe for the outcome of "first" group, while determining the outcome of the "second" group:

```
for pair in pairs: 
    if group_rank == ``first'' and win_prob >= runif(1):
        outcome <- ``win''
    else:
        outcome <- ``loss''

    if group_rank == ``second'':
        if outcome == ``win'' for group with group_rank == ``first'':
            outcome <- ``loss''
        else:
            outcome <- ``win''
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this within the tidyverse framework?

Comment: Why tidyverse tag?

Comment: I'm interested in a solution within the tidyverse framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` one could do this:

```
res <- c("win", "lose") # Not a good name but this is one of two possible results.
setDT(df)[, 
          outcome := {
            temp = win_prob[1] >= runif(1); 
            ifelse(c(temp, temp), res, rev(res))
          }, 
          by = pair]
df
   pair group group_rank win_prob outcome
1:    A     1      first      0.6     win
2:    A     2     second      0.4    lose
3:    B     3      first      0.5    lose
4:    B     4     second      0.5     win
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(pair) %>%
  mutate(temp = win_prob[1] >= runif(1)) %>%
  mutate(outcome = ifelse(temp, res, rev(res))) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

**NOTE:**
Both solutions assume data is already sorted so that for each pair, group_rank first is always appears above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second solution looks great! Do you think there is a way to execute it without assuming that the group_rank column is ordered in each pair?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. But sure - see the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot snoram! I think this solution may still assume that, though, as the first outcome for the ifelse winn make win, loss, while the second loss, win, thus it assumes that groups are ordered by first and second?

Comment: You're right! but easy to circumvent Just start by doing `df <- df[order(df$group_rank),]` and you are good to go.

Comment: Ye, also arrange(group_rank, .by_group = TRUE) would work here. Cheers.